# Must declare a named package when importing scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, import, compiler-errors, initialization

The error is on line one and says "Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module"

What does this mean and how do  I fix it?

the console  says that it was

> Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Main.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String sentance = keyboard.nextLine();



   System.out.println(sentance);
  }
}
```

Comment: Rename your class - naming a class 'Main' is not a good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Main.java` is direct under the `project/src` folder.

Java don't allow such a file structure. You must create a **package** as a directory under your `project/src` folder. For example, if your `Main.java`'s package name is `stackoverflow`, you must create `project/src/stackoverflow` directory and place your `Main.java` there. In addition to that, you must also **declare the package name** in the top of your `Main.java`.

[image: screenshot]